# Wants to echo and edit table data from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this code which can echo all table data. But if i want to edit that data from html page then what changes i need to do ?

```
<?php

    // list all the table in database
    $result = mysql_query("show tables");

    // show all the field with type, lenght,description of a specific table
    $result = mysql_query("DESCRIBE pub_log");

    // show a specific tables row 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pub_log");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $table="<table><tr>";
        $firstLine="<tr>";

            foreach ($r as $k => $v){
                $table .="<td>".$k."</td>";
                $firstLine .="<td>".$v."</td>";
            }

            $table.="</tr>".$firstLine."</tr>";

            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $table.="<tr>";

                foreach($r as $k => $v)
                    $table.="<td>".$v."</td>";
                    $table.="</tr>";
                }

                $table .="</table>";
                echo $table;
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What changes do you need to do? *Stop* using `mysql_`  interface for new development, and use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. For the love all that is good and beautiful in this world, just **stop**.

Comment: Yes i want to edit those row under those tables.. via html page how cum this possible?

Comment: You need your tables to be editable, you need to send the edited data back to server using Ajax or something and then update the database.

Comment: can you re-edit this code?